# zsh: Expand a previous argument in the current command line

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

I find myself often wanting to do simple commands like:

`cp /really/long/path/from/file.txt /really/long/path/to/file.txt`

Although I already use shortcuts like `!!` and `!$` often, it would be nice to be able to reference the last argument in the *current* command line (and optionally expand it for editing). Is there a way to do this in zsh, or some other equivalent trick to save time?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In general, you can refer to individual words in the current command line using history expansion.

```
$ cp /really/long/path/from/file.txt !#:1:s/from/to
```

or

```
$ cp /really/long/path/from/file.txt !#:$:s/from/to
```

The `!#` is history expansion for the command line typed *so far*. `:1` specifies the first argument in that expansion (in ths case, the long file path). `:$` could be used instead to refer to the last argument, independent of how many arguments have been typed so far.  `:s/from/to` performs text substitution on the selected word.

For this task, you can also use brace expansion:

```
$ cp /really/long/path/{from,to}/file.txt
```

(Note: both of these are taken from `bash`, but also work in `zsh`. There may be other `zsh`-only tricks that I am not aware of.)

Comment: Perfect, those two features were exactly what I was looking for. I think brace expansion is probably the smarter way of going about it, especially since I'm likely to forget `!#` means the current line

Answer (score 2):

You can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand stuff on zsh. For example:

If I do this command first

```
% ls /etc
```

And in this next line I do

```
% !!<Tab>
```

The `!!` will be replaced with

```
% ls /etc
```

So I can edit this the way I want. This works for a lot of things like `*` and Environment variables. For example tapping the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after `$TERM`, will replace (expand it) with (for example in my case) `xterm-256color`

Comment: That's helpful - I didn't know you could expand history in the current command line. Do you know if there's a way to "undo" an expansion?

Comment: not sure with the emacs bindings, but with the vi bindings you hit `esc` then `u` to undo the last action.

Comment: This means the previous first argument can be expanded with `!!:1` just for clarity :)